# AIC between glm and gam

Tags: aic, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

What are the consequences of comparing the AIC from a logistic regression model (glm) to the AIC from a generalized additive model (gam with binomial link and REML)? Here's an example of two models, are the AIC values comparable?

````r
library(mgcv)

nobs <- 100

set.seed(1)

x1 <- rnorm(nobs, 3, 3)
x2 <- rnorm(nobs)

z <- -2 + 2*x1 - 0.5*x1^2 + rnorm(nobs)

y <- rbinom(n=nobs, size=1, 
            prob={exp(z) / (1 + exp(z))})

df <- data.frame(y=y, x1=x1, x2=x2)

rm(x1, x2, z, y)

logit_mod <- glm(y ~ poly(x1, 2, raw=TRUE) + x2, 
                 family=binomial, data=df)

summary(logit_mod)

mean_x1 <- mean(df$x1)
mean_x2 <- mean(df$x2)

newdata = data.frame(x1=mean_x1, x2=mean_x2)

predict(logit_mod, newdata=newdata, 
        type="response")

plogis(coef(logit_mod)[1])

gam_mod <- gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2), 
               family=binomial, method="REML", 
               data=df, select=TRUE)

summary(gam_mod)

predict(gam_mod, newdata=newdata, 
          type="response")

plogis(coef(gam_mod)[1])

plot(gam_mod, pages=1, all.terms=TRUE)

sapply(list(logit_mod, gam_mod), AIC)

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are comparable, but you shouldn't be using REML to compare models with different fixed effects. Use `method = "ML"` in the `gam()` call if you are comparing your polynomial fits with the smooth version.

You could fit your GLM via `gam()` instead and as there are no penalised terms it would be fitted using the same algorithm as used by `glm()`.

```r
r$> m_glm <- glm(y ~ poly(x1, 2, raw = TRUE) + x2, family = binomial, data = df)
r$> m_glm_2 <- gam(y ~ poly(x1, 2, raw = TRUE) + x2,
                     family = binomial, data = df, method = "ML")
r$> m_gam <- gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2),
                    family = binomial, data = df, method = "ML")           
r$> AIC(m_glm, m_glm_2, m_gam)            
              df      AIC
m_glm   4.000000 75.72616
m_glm_2 4.000000 75.72616
m_gam   5.072922 78.50021
```

As there may be slight implementation differences, I would fit the GLM via `gam()`, and note that `AIC()` for a GAM in mgcv is going to be correcting for the smoothing parameters having been estimated, which involves a correction to the EDF of the model (though this is taken care of for you via the `logLik()` method for `"gam"` classed objects.

Comment: It's not required to use the "ML" method in order to do likelihood-based estimation and compute the AIC?

Comment: OOps, sorry; you shouldn't be comparing models with REML like this. I copied across the wrong example from my terminal. Will fix